# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection, unable to find common name

Tags: soap

I am trying to by pass or `disableCertificateValidation()` and trying to make https connection to my SOAP web service. When I am doing this its throwing the following error:

```
13:21:25.476 [WARN ] o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http:/****.xsd/}****ervice#{http://****.xsd/}get****servicePort has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64) ~[cxf-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[cxf-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516) [cxf-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425) [cxf-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326) [cxf-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279) [cxf-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:81) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.CglibProxyHelper$1.intercept(CglibProxyHelper.java:67) [cxf-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
```

Can some one please help on this ?

Comment: When we also tried to honor the certificate , the error remained the same as it was..the approach we tried was

Answer (score 0):

When we also tried to honor the certificate , the error remained the same as it was..the approach we tried was

```
public static void setupTLS(***servicePort port) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{

    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();

    String keyStoreLoc = "certificates/***-keystore.ks";
    String keyPassword = "*****";

    final KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource(keyStoreLoc);
    ksp.setPassword(keyPassword);

    final KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    kmp.setKeyPassword(keyPassword);

    TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();
    tlsCP.setKeyManagers(kmp.createKeyManagers());
    tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);
    tlsCP.setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultHostnameVerifier(false);
    tlsCP.setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory(true);
    tlsCP.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
    {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Creating Trust Manager
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager()
    {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
        {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
        }
    } };

    tlsCP.setTrustManagers(trustAllCerts);

    httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
```

Still no success as the error still remains the same

Comment: Please edit the question to add details. Answers are reserved for solutions.